# having trouble styling my contact us slider

Tags: css

I have been trying to style my "contact us" slider window but for my lack of knowledge (started website designing only a month back for my own project) I am kinda stuck. 
The functionality is working great, but there are a few issues:

1. "contact us" text and a image that I am trying to get in a line is
   not working.
2. in collapse mode, div containing text "contact us" is getting
   reduced width wise.

Please excuse my not-so-technical language, since I am new to the concept..  Please refer my website koncreteplanet.com..  also, I have created a jsfiddle to give a glimpse of the code I am using (https://jsfiddle.net/jjff2o2x/). Thanks in advance!!

Javascript code:

```
jQuery("#ContactUs_header").click(function () {
   jQuery('#slideContactUsbox').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

HTML / PHP code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="contactus-panel">
        <div class="contactus-panel">
            <div id="ContactUs_header" class="contactus_footer" >
                <a  href="#"><p>Contact Us</p></a>

                <img align="right" width=auto height="40px" src= "<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory') . "/image/handshake.png" ;  ?>">

            </div>

            <div id="slideContactUsbox" class="contactus-extended">
                <div class="container" style="width:300px;align:left;" id="MailUs-Panel">
                    <form name="Form-MailUs" id="Form-MailUs" method="post" action=<?php echo (get_template_directory_uri() . "/contactus/html_form_send.php"); ?> >
                        <div class="">
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control mailflds" name="first_name" id="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30" placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control mailflds" name="email" id="email" maxlength="80" size="30" placeholder="E-Mail">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <input  type="text" class="form-control mailflds" name="telephone" id="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30" placeholder="Mobile / Landline Number">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <textarea  name="comments" id="comments" class="form-control mailflds" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Enter your comments"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div>
                            <Button class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-custom" id="Submit_MailUs" name="Submit_MailUs">Submit</Button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="ack-mailus-err" style="color:red;font-family:garamond;font-size:18px;text-align:center;">
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>

                <div id="ack-mailus" style="color:green;font-family:garamond;font-size:18px;text-align:center;">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>   <!--    end of contactus panel    -->  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.contactus-panel{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    z-index:9999;

}

.contactus_footer{
    position:relative;
    /*z-index: 10;  */
    /*float:right; */
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 1.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5px 2px 4px 15px;
    font-family:'Raleway', garamond, sans-serif;
    font-size:20px;
    background-color: #084000;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.contactus_footer a {
    color: #fff;
}
.contactus-extended{
    background-color:#fff;  
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: How do we know the issue?

Comment: Sorry, but it got submitted accidentally before I could have completed my query. Please refer it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`slideToggle()` is jQuery method. Please using jQuery.

https://jsfiddle.net/pgqnjdvp/

Comment: used jsfiddle for the first time... may have done something wrong entering in information in there.. but issue I am facing is with styling.. most probably a css fix should help.. jquery part is working just fine on the actual site atleast.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve both parts of the issue.. can't believe it was that simple.. for part 2: I just added width exclusively to the container and it ceased to exist...  also resolved part 1 of the issue..  added float and vertical-align:middle to both the text and img element styling too in addition to the div class and got the desired result.